# Couldn't generate jwt token with a nodejs sign-in

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to singin with existing user but it shows `Cannot POST /api/signin`. The same works with signup process and I did cross check the signin route but couldn't find where exactly the issue occurs.

signin code:

```
exports.signin = (req,res) => {
    User.findOne({email:req.body.email})
    .exec((error,user) => {
        if(error) return res.status(400).json({error});
        if(user){
            if(user.authenticate(req.body.password)){
                const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id},process.env.JWT_SECRET,{expiresIn:'1h'})
                const {firstName,lastName,email,role,fullName} = user;
                res.status(200).json({
                    token,
                    user:{
                        firstName,lastName,email,role,fullName
                    }
                })
            } else {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message:"Invalid Password"
                })
            }
        }else{
            return res.status(400).json({
                message:"Something went wrong!"
            })
        }
    })
}
```

router : `router.get('/signin',signin)`

app: `app.use('/api',authRoutes);`

Tried calling postman with : `localhost:2000/api/signin` but dint work.
The same route pattern for signup worked `localhost:2000/api/signup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are doing a `post` request while in your `router` you are handling a `get`. Change it to this :

```js
router.post('/signin',signin)
```